# iron-overlay-backdrop style not being applied

Tags: css, polymer

I have a custom element which has an iron-overlay-backdrop as a child element (inside a paper-dialog). I am trying to increase the fade time (which I can do if I can edit the css in chrome). When I try and apply changes to the style --iron-overlay-backdrop the changes are not being applied in the child. What I have is:

```
<style>
:host {
    --iron-overlay-backdrop: {transition: opacity 5s;};
}
</style>
```

I have also tried something simpler with --iron-overlay-backdrop-opacity: 0.8 which does not work either. For some reason the style is not being applied. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong, or how I can get the desired behavior of a longer transition time?

Answer (score 0):

The custom property for the overlay backdrop is : --iron-overlay-backdrop-opacity
you can set the opacity of the host and it's transition this way

```
:host{
opacity: var(--iron-overlay-backdrop-opacity, 0.8);
  transition: opacity 5s;
}
```

Comment: That did not seem to solve my problem, it had no change on the shadow dom of the iron-overly-backdrop at all. Verified via chrome that the style still reports opacity of 0.6 and transition of 0.2s. What element would I put this styling in? The over all structure of my app is:
`
<myapp>
<style>
:host{
opacity: .....
</style>
<template>
<paper-dialog></paper-dialog>
</template>
<script>
...
</script> `